# How can I create automated keyboard scripts?

Tags: keyboard, scripts, shortcuts

Is it possible to do the following in Ubuntu? If so can someone point me in the right direction.

Say you want to set a keyboard shortcut to do the following:

For examples sake, set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open Firefox and maximize it, but only if Firefox is not already running. If it is running and not maximized, then maximize the most recently touched Firefox window. If it is maximized, then minimize Firefox.

Thanks, Joe

Comment: @joemangrove I'm curious to know: did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like something [AutoKey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) would be good for.

From the Ubuntu Software Center:

> AutoKey is a desktop automation
>   utility for Linux and X11. It allows
>   the automation of virtually any task
>   by responding to typed abbreviations
>   and hotkeys. It offers a full-featured
>   GUI that makes it highly accessible
>   for novices, as well as a scripting
>   interface offering the full
>   flexibility and power of the Python
>   language.

It can be installed by clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/autokey).

[image: Screenshot of AutoKey from screenshots.debian.net]

Answer (score 0):

Go to: **System**, **Settings**, **Keyboard Shortcuts**, **Add**.

Chose a name and copy the following command:

```
xdg-open http://google.com
```

make sure the url you choose has http:// or https:// in front of it, otherwise, it will be interpreted, for instance, as a path on the local file system, which is opened with Nautilus or what ever.

If you want to find other interesting commands to put in those fields for short cuts, why not *get your geek on* at http://www.commandlinefu.com.

rev.: this answer made much simpler thanks to Roger Pate

Comment: The command could also be `xdg-open http://google.com`.